# PHP - Allow access from only one domain

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have kind of a strange situation right now. Basically, my company is currently putting links to the latest builds of our software behind a gate, but once the user signs in, they can distribute the link to the builds. Free 30-day trials, unaccounted for.

So I would like to block access to URL `/downloads/file.extension`, or even just `/downloads/` entirely, unless the referring URL is `allowed_domain.com`.

I would ***love*** to use `.htaccess`, but the hosting provider (WP Engine) we use has their servers set up on Nginx. Not only that, but I have to send my Nginx code to WP Engine for them to implement for me, which is not practical.

Thus, ***I am looking for a PHP ONLY solution***, or a WordPress plugin that I apparently didn't notice.

And yes, I know this is a really stupid way for my company to be storing important files, but I need to fix this now until they come up with a better way.

Comment: And yes, I know that I should host these kinds of files outside `public_html`, and leverage PHP to send them, but WP Engine doesn't give me access to the true root.

Comment: I believe Wordpress only rewrites URIs for files that don't exist. So if the files exist in a public facing directory, I don't think there is anything you can do to prevent downloads using PHP only.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I'm not trying to re-write URLs. I'm just trying to redirect unless they come from a specific URL.

Comment: I know. What I was trying to say was that any PHP code you write can't intercept a request for a file. If the file is public, then it is public and there is nothing that you write in PHP that can stop it.

Comment: So the only way to block access to those files is through nginx code or by putting them outside of public_html which you already mentioned. Just out of curiosity, why is it not practical to send your nginx code to the hosting provider? You could just make one change that will let you prevent access to any file through PHP code.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I'm a front end guy, so I don't know the first thing about Nginx code. I'd want to fiddle around and test it, rather than send off some code of which I know nothing and hope it works. I'll contact our host provider and see if storing outside of public_html is an option for me.

Comment: It appears that you're correct though. No mater what FreedomPride1 and I tried, the code didn't seem to work when I was trying to restrict a file. If you wanna put an answer below, I'll award it to you.

Comment: Wil do. By the way, you should be able to test your nginx code on your own computer before you send it to them. I've found this program which sets up an nginx server with PHP: https://wtserver.wtriple.com/. That is for Windows. If you don't have Windows I'm sure there is a comparable software for your OS.

Comment: @KodosJohnson, I'm interested from a learning perspective, but my company decided to invest in a more formal solution (probably the right move). Does the technique you're proposing require me to be able to store content outside of `public_html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do what you described. That is because when someone tries to access a file from the site, the web server will first check if it exists and if it does, it will serve the file immediately. It does not go through any PHP code. Therefore you cannot write any PHP code that will intercept this request and block it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method that I'm using it.
Enjoy.

You're going to need to list down those IP address.

```
<?php $allow = array("201.168.0.1", "456.789.123", "789.123.456"); //allowed IPs

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow)) {

    header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/index.php"); //redirect

    exit();

} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This looks more or less what I'm looking for, but I'm a front-end guy, so I have some really basic questions before I can even test out your code: can I put this in the PHP file with all the rest of my PHP code?

Comment: @JesseRogers, basically could you either make this file into index.php.
So when user triggers `www.yourdomain.com/index.php` it will check for the user IP address then will redirect to your php. Maybe you can name the php something else like `www.yourdomain.com/main.php` so only user with those IP will redirect and the rest won't. If it helps, click it as an answer :D

Comment: Will definitely award you the answer if/when I can get your answer to work, since you answered first. Sorry, I just need a lot of help with back end code, haha. Another question — `location: http://yourdomain.com/index.php`. Is that where the user is sent if they don't come from an allowed IP? Or is that the URL I'm trying to protect?

Comment: @JesseRogers, that's the allowed IP . When their IP is in the list only they will be redirected . The users who are not in the list will just see a blank page or you could redirect them to another site. This script serves as a filter .

Comment: Well the script is doing something now, but it's redirecting my entire site to the URL I specified inside `header()`. If I put this in a PHP file inside the folder I'm trying to protect, would that work?

Comment: Yes it would . basically you don't redirect but you put the content in the redirect part when the user is listed in the IP's above. Users who are not in the list couldn't view anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136295/discussion-between-jesse-rogers-and-freedompride).

Comment: I think you have to click "continue this discussion in chat" to join.

Comment: I've messaged in the chat.